# Can i define in the persistence.xml two database?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I'm working on an application in Java EE. I must use two database ,how can I define two database in my persistence.xml?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Create another persistence-unit in your exisiting persistent.xml and give it a different name. Then create another entity manager depending on newly added persistent unit.